# how to return the value or string form another method

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I have `String` `"sequence"`. I replaced the string by `replacement()` method and I want to return replaced `String` using the `sequence()` method, which returns the `String` only.
I tried but it only returns `"sequence"` which is not replaced. Any suggestion?

```java
public class Sequnce {
    str ="sequence";

    public String replacement(String orginal, String new){
        orginal = "se"
        new = "Se"
        str.replace(original, new);

        return str
    }

    public String sequence() { 
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to see a preview of your question before submitting. Please double check things like the indentation before asking. This is a mess. Your question will get most activity immediately after being asked. If you genuinely want an answer, you need to spend time making your question the best it can be.

Comment: Sorry about it this is my beginner using this platform.

Comment: `new` is a keyword by the way. You can't name a parameter that. You also need semi-colons

Comment: Hello, please update your code so that it could compile and print any output.  You may need to read an article how [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

String objects are immutable, so calling a method on a String object won't change it. But you can return its result (which is a new String object).

```
public String replacement(String orginal, String replacement){
    return str.replace(original, replacement);
}
```

Comment: then what should i do with String sequence() method?? I tried it returns the unreplaced string...

Comment: Of course, that what is does. What do you expect? Use replacement() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar. from [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
So in your example, you can do it like this:

```
public class Main
{
    String str = "SAquAncA";
    

    public void replacement(char original, char new_char)
    {
        str = str.replace(original, new_char);
    }

    public String sequence() { 
        return str;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.replacement('A','e');
        System.out.println( obj.sequence() );
    }
}
```

The result :
`Sequence`